# How to differentiate original and fake Apple 5W USB EU power adapter A1400 / MD813ZM/A?

Tags: iphone, charging

I did receive a European 5 watt USB charger model A1400 that claims to be from Apple. The charger even claims to be designed by Apple in California and made in China. Possibly by "Salcomp".

The "made in China" part, is most likely a valid claim.

But how can I find out whether this USB charger is a counterfeit or a genuine Apple product?

I do own a genuine A1300 that came with an iPhone that was bought in an Apple store in Oberhausen. The 230V pins two USB chargers are shown in the photograph below:

[image: Apple 5W USB charger A1300 and possibly fake A1400 230V contact pins]

Here is a photograph of the serial imprint inside the USB connector from both an "A1400" and an original A1300:
[image: A1400 and A1300 serial imprint inside USB connector]

And here the imprint the "Certification Label" of a <strike>possible</strike> counterfeit A1400:
[image: Possible counterfeit Apple A1400 charger a.k.a. MD813ZM/A its Certification Label]

PS I am aware of the A1300 to A1400 Exchange program and don't use the A1300 any longer for charging purposes.

Comment: If you're interested in a sort of poll, I'd vote counterfeit: the plug-side label's fonts are inconsistent (especially the kerning) and the Apple logo is narrower than it should be. The chamfer on the plug pins is also terrible, which agrees with @Elf's report.

Comment: The spaces missing after the double colon (:) is a clear sign of counterfeit.

Answer (score 1):

I got here by having the same problem as you and googling it. :)

I got my 5W EU charger (i'm sure now that it's fake) from a local seller, because my brand new SE was for UK market, so i had their three pin charger in the box. The one that i bought had a problem i noticed shortly. When i tried to charge my SE with it, touch sensitivity would go crazy. I compared it with my girls charger (she got it with her 6S in the box, for French market) and it was working flawlessly. There are couple differences between those two. Metal pins are different, fake one is lighter and you can bend the plastic housing a little when you press it harder.
They even made serial number readable, but pins and weight betrayed them.
I will post pics tomorrow when there is daylight so i can make better macros.

Answer (score 1):

There is no apple icon in the original one.

[image]

This link might also help.
https://support.apple.com/en-za/usbadapter-european