# Verify if my 18W Apple charger is original

Tags: charger

Is this Apple original adapter?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243541/how-to-differentiate-original-and-fake-apple-5w-usb-eu-power-adapter-a1400-md8 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349293/is-this-macbook-charger-counterfeit

Comment: If you bought it from Apple directly then it's original.  If not, then we have no way of knowing.  You should assume it's not original.

Comment: As @fsb said if you bought it from Apple it's an original Mac product. I tried googling the long alpha-numeric listed at the bottom of the adapter but no luck.  If you bought it from a 3rd party site it is probably not an original Apple product. Apple may sell them so start your search at Apple.com

Comment: What is the reason for you to doubt it’s authenticity?

Comment: I brought an iPad second hand , that’s why asking.